# Как удалить слово при подключении удаленного javascript?

Tags: javascript

На сайте подключен внешний удаленный javascript таким образом:

```
<script async src="https://site.ru/smi.js"></script>
```

В файле содержится в разных местах слово "Реклама", которое нужно удалить. Как это сделать?

Пробовал на php командой `$javafile = str_replace('Реклама', '', $var);` , но ничего не вышло естественно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На чужом сервере вы этим файлом распоряжаться, конечно, не можете. Но вы можете его скачать и удалить из него что угодно.

Если очень хочется, то можно делать это прям на лету.

```
<script async src="https://your_site.ru/smi.js.php"></script>
```

и такой прокси:

```
<?php // smi.js.php

$smiJs = file_get_contents('https://site.ru/smi.js');

echo str_replace('Реклама', '', $smiJs);
```